# Querying Assisted Conversions with a Conversion Segment in R

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the `googleAnalyticsR` package. Since Google Analytics accounts all have different configurations, a MWE isn't possible, but I'll at least provide the relevant code, which queries from the v3 API:

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
ga_auth()
google_analytics(id = ga_id, 
                 start = start_date, 
                 end = end_date,
                 metrics = c("assistedConversions", "assistedValue",
                             "lastInteractionConversions", "lastInteractionValue"),
                 dimensions = c("nthDay"), 
                 samplingLevel = "WALK",
                 segment = "sessions::condition::ga:landingPagePath=@/some_string",
                 type = "mcf")
```

The variables `ga_id`, `start_date`, and `end_date` are numeric, string, and string respectively, with the dates in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I am trying to execute the query above, which pulls Assisted Conversions, the values of these Assisted Conversions, Last Interaction Conversions, and the values of these Last Interaction Conversions from the Multi-Channel funnel.

The main problem is the `segment` argument above. When I run this query, it pulls everything for the entire website and does not appear to be applying the segment. If I were to create a conversion segment under Conversions > Assisted Conversions > Conversion Segments, when I run

```
ga_segment_list() %>% .$items %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(name)
```

the segment I created doesn't even show up. I also have the same segment under Admin > Segments, and using `gaid::` with the `segment_id` does not work either.

Is there any way to me to pull these data that I seek? I'm open to using a different `R` package for this if there's one available.

Comment: Good question! Given that conversion segments are not listed in the query explorer (which I think still uses v3) I would guess that they are simply not available via the API (and "normal" segments do not apply to that report).

Comment: I believe that MCF API doesn't support segments. At least the API docs have no mention of segment parameter. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference#data_response